# What does the final "'s" refer to?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> A great way to explore the town and the neighbouring villages of Shottery and Wilmcote, home to Anne Hathaway's Cottage and Shakespeare's mother **Mary Arden's**, is with City Sightseeing's 'Hop On Hop Off' buses.

Do the words in bold mean "*the cottage of Mary Arden*", "*[the house/place/establishment of](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%27s#Particle) Mary Arden*" or something else?

Comment: It does refer to Mary Arden's cottage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible and usually desirable to not repeat a noun in an {adjective} {noun} structure if you have more than one noun and the second noun is the same.

> I took the red sock and the blue sock.
>
> I took the red sock and the blue.

That example above is grammatically correct but awkward sounding. Usually one would say *I took the red sock and the blue one*.

But, with possessive adjectives, simply eliding the last noun is more common and less awkward.

> Over the hill I saw Mark's camping equipment, and John's camping equipment too.
>
> Over the hill I saw Mark's camping equipment, and John's too.

Comment: Or I saw both Mark's and John's equipment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

> Arden's

is possesive, for the pattern *noun* + "*'s*" it is usually posessive.

Possesive can be used as a short for meaning *place*

> Let's meet at yours.
>   *Let's meet at your place*
>
> Mary Arden's
>   *Mary Arden's place (house)*

Your original sentence would be expanded to

> home to Anne Hathaway's Cottage and Shakespeare's mother Mary Arden's
>   home to Anne Hathaway's Cottage and Shakespeare's mother Mary Arden's *cottage*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does mean "Shakespeare's mother's cottage" but given your confusion you can see how this is a clumsily-worded sentence.  There are several other options which would be more clear:

> ... home to the cottages of both Anne Hathaway and Shakespeare's mother Mary Arden,
>
> ... home to Anne Hathaway's cottage and Shakespeare's mother Mary Arden's cottage,
>
> ... where you will find the cottages of Shakespeare's wife, Anne Hathaway, and his mother, Mary Arden,